# How to import psycopg2 into a new module im writing

Tags: python-3.x, module, importerror

So to simplify, I'm trying to write my own module (`test.py`) that looks as follows:

```
import psycopg2

get_data(xyz):


    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="",
                                  password="",
                                  host="",
                                  port="",
                                  database="")

    last_qry = """select * from xyz.abc"""

    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(last_qry)

    last_data = cursor.fetchone()

    cursor.close()

    connection.close()

    return last_data
```

in a different file I am running:

```
import test

get_data(xyz)
```

and I get the following error:

```
name 'psycopg2' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install psycopg2 with pip or other python pkg mangers?

Comment: Yes i did. So when i put the get_data function in my main python file, it works. Its just when i have it inside my module i get the error.

Comment: Are you saying your `get_data` definition is in a different file than your `import psycopg2` statement?

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs in these code snippets that you put here:

1. Your import should be like this:

   ```
   from test import get_data
   ```

   or in this way:

   ```
   import test
   test.get_data()
   ```
2. What is the use of `xyz` ? the second code snippet must return
   `NameError` because `xyz` is not define;if you want to use it in `last_qry` you must have `.format()` for it.
3. What is the structure of directory that included the second file ?
   and where is the first file?